# ffmpeg - av_interleaved_write_frame(): Unknown error Error number -10053

Tags: java, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, ftp-client

Using ffmpeg, I am able to stream video. I wrote socket Java program that connects to TCP and reading this the Live stream.

After my Java program finished recording, ffmpeg is stopping with following the error unexpectedly. I would like to keep ffmpeg running the whole time.

> av_interleaved_write_frame(): Unknown error Error writing trailer of
>   tcp://XX.XX.XX.XX:5800?listen: Error number -10053 curred

The ffmpeg command I am using:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f gdigrab -an -sn -framerate 7 -i desktop -video_size 800x600 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -maxrate 4000k -crf 40 -bufsize 8000k -probesize 32 -f mpegts tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:5800?listen
```

Java code:

```
DataInputStream ois = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
while((n = ois.read(buf)) != -1 && n!=3 ){
    fos.write(buf,0,n);
    fos.flush();
    cnt--;
    if(cnt ==0) break;
}
```

Comment: If you use different machines for sending and receiving and I assume both side somewhat uses ffmpeg libraries, difference maybe the ffmpeg library version difference that may cause problem.

Comment: Kamil, i am testing on the same VDI where ffmpeg is deployed.